# StackExchange OpenId authentication to Data Explorer broken

Tags: bug, data-explorer, login, stack-exchange-openid

I have been unable to [log in to StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/) using StackExchange OpenID for several hours today.  If I try, it says:

> ### An error occurred on the server
>
> **This event has been recorded.**
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, [please report it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=stackexchange-openid).

...so I'm reporting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working now. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?